# iOS volume buttons in js

Tags: javascript, ios, button, web-applications, volume

I'm developing a web app and would like to use the volume controls on an iPhone as an input for one handed use (jump and duck), the problem is that this is a web app and iOS safari blocks js from accessing the volume. 
Why would the getter for volume be blocked and is there a way around this?